# How to change data returned by JSON?

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular2-observables

I am using the OMDB api (Online Movie DB). I have created an interface that returns the expected data types. When requesting data via the http get method, the data that is returned is: {Search: Array(10), totalResults: "31", Response: "True"}. The data that I need is in the Search Array. When subscribing I use res.Search to access this info: subscribe( (res) => { res = this.movieResults = res.Search; however the error says that Search does not exist on my interface. How can I fix this please?

/* My Interface */

```
export interface SearchInterface {
    Poster: string;
    Title: string;
    Type: string;
    Year: string;
    imdbID: string;
}
```

export default SearchInterface;

/* The get method in my Service */

```
searchFilm(name: string): Observable<SearchInterface> {
    return this.http.get<SearchInterface>(this.searchUrl + this.apiKey + '&s=' + name);
  }
```

/* Subscribing to the observable in my component */

```
/* GET request*/
  getData(event) {
    const film = event.target.value;
    this.data.searchFilm(film)
    .subscribe( (res) => {
      /** Sort out res.Search issue */
      res = this.movieResults = res.Search;
      console.log(res);
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two data structures involved here: the outer one, returned by the http service, that you described in your question:

```
interface ActualResponse {
  Search: Array<SearchInterface>;
  totalResults: string;
  Response: string;
}
```

And the one you only care about, used for each element of the Search array: SearchInterface.

Your service doesn't transform the response you get from the server. So its return type can't possibly be `Observable<SearchInterface>`: the server returns an `ActualResponse`, so it should be `Observable<ActualResponse>`.

But a better design, since you don't care about the other parts of the actual response, would be to transform the actual response into what you actually care about: an `Array<SearchInterface>`. You can do that using the `map` operator:

```
searchFilm(name: string): Observable<Array<SearchInterface>> {
  return this.http.get<ActualResponse>(this.searchUrl + this.apiKey + '&s=' + name).pipe(
    map(response => response.Search)
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because your SearchInterface contains key

```
Poster: string;
Title: string;
Type: string;
Year: string;
imdbID: string;
```

But your data contains key

```
Search: Array(10), 
totalResults: "31", 
Response: "True"
```

You can do one thing as -

```
searchFilm(name: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get<any>(this.searchUrl + this.apiKey + '&s=' + name);
  }
```

and

```
movieResults: SearchInterface;
```

Answer (score 0):

@Amitk88 why are you exporting SearchInterface twice
`export interface SearchInterface` 
`export default SearchInterface;`

Also don't assign variable like this
`res = this.movieResults = res.Search;`

```
  getData(event) {
    const film = event.target.value;
    this.data.searchFilm(film)
    .subscribe( (res: SearchInterface ) => {
      console.log(res)
    });
  }
```

Check the response you get back. I don't see Search as a key in your interface but you are expecting to find Search in the response.
If you expect Search to be a key in the response then include it under the interface

Comment: Thank you for pointing out these issues, much appreaciated :-)

Answer (score 0):

I was creating a stackblitz and here we are with 3 answers already :)

@JB Nizet response is very elegant and that's what I would recommend too. Anyway, here is my contribution :

// random.service.ts

```
searchFilm(name: string): Observable<SearchInterface[]> {
    return this.http.get<ServerResponse>(this.searchUrl + this.apiKey + '&s=' + name).pipe(
      map(res => res.Search)
    );
  }
```

//random.component.ts

```
getData(event) {
    const film = event.target.value;
    this.searchFilm(film)

    .subscribe( (res) => {
      /** Sort out res.Search issue */
      // res = this.movieResults = res.Search;
      this.movieResults = res;
      console.log(res);
    });
  }
```

// ramdom.model.ts

```
export interface SearchInterface {
    Poster: string;
    Title: string;
    Type: string;
    Year: string;
    imdbID: string;
}

export interface ServerResponse 
   {Search: SearchInterface[], totalResults: number, Response: boolean}
```

[et voilà !](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qrvmpt?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Thank you for your response, much appreciated :-)